# Watch, build files and upload on server with PhpStorm and node-watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, phpstorm

I use node-watch script to watch any changes in files and rebuild project files with concat.

Files are building correctly but they are not uploading to server until I make double click - in app and PhpStorm. The problem is (probably) that watch function is asynchronous. I want to see changes in app immediately.

How to solve this issue?

```
watch('myFolderToWatch/js', {
    recursive: true,
    delay: 100
}, function(evt, name) {

    console.log('%s changed.', name);

    concat(filesToConcat, '../path_to_concat/').then(function (value) {
        console.log('test');
    });
});
```

Comment: IDE does not check for externally modified files every second -- only one app focus change. You can invoke such scan manually via `File | Synchronize`

Answer (score 1):

As @LazyOne has mentioned, changes made by your script are external for PhpStorm, it doesn't see the files generated by `concat` until you synchronize the IDE VFS either manually, via `File | Synchronize`, or by moving focus from IDE and back. thus deployment doesn't work.

as a workaround, I'd suggest using [File watchers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.1/using-file-watchers.html) instead:

- create a `concat.js` script
- add a new scope `myFolderToWatch` in **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes**, add files from your `myFolderToWatch/js` folders to it
- in **Settings | Tools | File Watchers**, add a new file watcher like this one:

[image]

if everything is set up correctly, Phpstporm will see the changes made to generated files and auto-upload them once you change the source files